# Cookie Consent Module locked me out

Tags: login, cookies

I've done something a little silly, I've been trying to put cookie consent module into a site. Somehow I've activated it, but I have no way to accept cookies and I cannot now log into the admin area of the site.

Is it possible to disable/uninstall plugins via Mysql database or some other way?